# How to iterate nested object keys with child nested

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to iterate the nested object keys which will be have inner child nested as well:

Nested object code:

```
{
    "F2C3C496-BEA6-A5E8-15F0-E2867304B463": {
        "D39FD497-9529-6CC3-70DE-E8D9277C18D3": {
            "child": {
                "87A1817D-CFA9-70FD-131B-224658AF13CE": {
                    "next": {
                        "F7A90266-B7F4-4CC2-0F1B-D4B320E2EC1A": {}
                    }
                }
            },
            "next": {
                "B49927ED-369E-E219-FC1A-8E4BAAFC3933": {
                    "next": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JS code to iterate:

```
flowThrough = (obj, callback, context?, path?: string) => {
    let nestedKey=';'
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      if(!isEmptyObject(key))
      callback(key, context, path);

      if (!isEmpty(obj[key]) && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        if(obj[key].hasOwnProperty('next'))
        nestedKey = obj[key].next;
        else if(obj[key].hasOwnProperty('child'))
        nestedKey = obj[key].child;
        else  nestedKey = obj[key];

        this.flowThrough(nestedKey, callback, context, (path)? has(context, path.concat(".next"))?path.concat(`.next[${get(context, path.concat(".next").length)}]`): path.concat('.').concat("next[0]") : key)
      }
    })
  }
```

Actually, the above code working for one nested level to get key(ids). If it reaches the empty object key then the loop is ending there. actually, it should check any other child/next is there or not.

Expected output:

```
{  "flow": [
    {
      "id": "F2C3C496-BEA6-A5E8-15F0-E2867304B463",
      "next": [
        {
          "id": "D39FD497-9529-6CC3-70DE-E8D9277C18D3",
          "child": [
            {
              "id": "87A1817D-CFA9-70FD-131B-224658AF13CE",
              "next": [
                {
                  "id": "F7A90266-B7F4-4CC2-0F1B-D4B320E2EC1A",
                  "next": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "next": [
            {
              "id": "B49927ED-369E-E219-FC1A-8E4BAAFC3933",
              "next": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please give me the solution for this.

Comment: what is the goal of the iteration, what are you trying to extract - what is the expected result?

Comment: @Kinglish - I have added the expected results. to get all the ids

Comment: A more precise description is needed about the possible shape of `obj`. For example, can there be more than one `id` key on each level of nesting?

Comment: @MikeM Yes it will have more than one id as well

Comment: @MikeM - any solution ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear - can there be more than one `child` or `next` per object? How about giving another example with multiple ids in the same object etc.

Comment: @MikeM yes it can be more than one child and next.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not going to try this. It's still not clear enough to me.

Comment: @MikeM - The main problem is recursive. when it's comes to end the 'obj'  passing empty '{}' so it's not iterating to the next level. so it's ending there itself. i want to have logic if it's empty object then loop has to check whether any child or next is there or not. this is what i need it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235104/discussion-between-bagya-and-mikem).

Comment: @MikeM - can you provide any example for stack?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let obj = {
  "F2C3C496-BEA6-A5E8-15F0-E2867304B463": {
    "D39FD497-9529-6CC3-70DE-E8D9277C18D3": {
      "child": {
        "87A1817D-CFA9-70FD-131B-224658AF13CE": {
          "next": {
            "F7A90266-B7F4-4CC2-0F1B-D4B320E2EC1A": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "next": {
        "B49927ED-369E-E219-FC1A-8E4BAAFC3933": {
          "next": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
const setObj = e => {
  let tmp = {}
  if (Array.isArray(e[0])) e = e[0]
  if (typeof e[0] === 'string' && e[0].split('-').length === 5) {
    tmp = {
      id: e[0],
      next: setObj(Object.entries(e[1]))
    };
  } else if (e[1]) {
    tmp = {
      child: setObj(Object.entries(e[1]))
    };
  }
  return tmp
}
let newobj = Object.entries(obj).map(setObj)[0]
console.log(newobj)
```

Original answer...
Here's one way to go about it. Use a recursive function along with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to gather the data. I found that the result was a series of nested arrays of id's - so I flattened them all with `join()` and then split them again. Finally, `filter()` helped remove the empty array indexes

```js
let obj = {
  "F2C3C496-BEA6-A5E8-15F0-E2867304B463": {
    "D39FD497-9529-6CC3-70DE-E8D9277C18D3": {
      "child": {
        "87A1817D-CFA9-70FD-131B-224658AF13CE": {
          "next": {
            "F7A90266-B7F4-4CC2-0F1B-D4B320E2EC1A": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "next": {
        "B49927ED-369E-E219-FC1A-8E4BAAFC3933": {
          "next": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
const getKeys = e => {
  let ret = []
  if (e[0].split('-').length === 5) ret.push(e[0]);
  if (e[1]) ret.push(Object.entries(e[1]).map(getKeys))
  return ret.join(',')
}
let keys = Object.entries(obj).map(getKeys)[0].split(",").filter(e => e)
console.log(keys)
```

Comment: actually, I need with nested level here you're reading all the ids in one short.  To give you more clarity I need id on each iteration. the reason I need it that way i have to do a callback with that id ( level of nested it's required)

Comment: can you show the expected result in your question verbatim?

Comment: 1st iteration --> F2C3C496-BEA6-A5E8-15F0-E2867304B463
2nd Iteration-->D39FD497-9529-6CC3-70DE-E8D9277C18D3
3rd Iteration --> 87A1817D-CFA9-70FD-131B-224658AF13CE 

4th Iteration-->F7A90266-B7F4-4CC2-0F1B-D4B320E2EC1A

for each iteration i am doing callback to form a nested json with various datas

Comment: so returning the level with the ID is sufficient? like [{id:'F7A90266-B7F4-4CC2-0F1B-D4B320E2EC1A', level:4}, ...]? or do you need to call the callback inside the iteration?

Comment: I need to call the callback inside each iteration. let me share json which is required to form after returning the callback

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.e71a3adaad5c41d0a8a746841c30f7e4&right=local.gibahi - final json which i am forming in the callback.

Comment: can you help me to achieve on the above output. i tried but it's taking only one nested level

Comment: @bagya - actually i've tried a couple times and got somewhat close, but the inconsistency of the data pattern threw me, and I ended up getting busy elsewhere. If I can, I'll try again.

Comment: I updated my answer, but since you changed the link of the reference object. I am not sure if it's what you're looking for. You should post the example of the expected result in your question so everyone has a chance to answer

Comment: I have updated the expected result. could you please check it?

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.e71a3adaad5c41d0a8a746841c30f7e4&right=local.gibahi - this is what i need to get output while looping nested object